# Removing columns with empty labels in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the below Pandas DataFrame.  It may be hard to tell with this formatting but columns 4 and 6 have no headers (the cols with values like `@` and `L (-14)`).  I'm trying to run `pd.numeric()` on this but am getting an error `Columns must be same length as key`.  I have to assume it's these blank column headers causing this issue.

```
    G   Date    Age Tm      Opp     GS  MP  FG  ... DRB TRB AST STL BLK TOV PF  PTS GmSc    +/-
Rk                                                                                  
1   1   2003-10-29  18-303  CLE @   SAC L (-14) 1   42:50   12  ... 4   6   9   4   0   2   3   25  24.7    -9
2   2   2003-10-30  18-304  CLE @   PHO L (-9)  1   40:21   8   ... 10  12  8   1   0   7   1   21  14.7    -3
3   3   2003-11-01  18-306  CLE @   POR L (-19) 1   39:10   3   ... 4   4   6   2   0   2   3   8   5.0 -21
4   4   2003-11-05  18-310  CLE     DEN L (-4)  1   41:06   3   ... 9   11  7   2   3   2   1   7   11.2    -3
5   5   2003-11-07  18-312  CLE @   IND L (-1)  1   43:44   8   ... 5   5   3   0   0   7   2   23  9.0 -7
```

I've tried a lot of ways but can't seem to remove them in any clean way.  I've tried removing them via `df.iloc[:,[4,6]]` but they're not "in key" when I try to do that.

Please advise -- thanks!

Comment: can you do `df.columns.tolist()` and share the results. Also, did you try df.reset_index(drop=True). It looks like a multi level dataframe

Comment: list form looks like: `['G',
 'Date',
 'Age',
 'Tm',
 '\xa0',
 'Opp',
 '\xa0',
 'GS',
 'MP',
 'FG',
 'FGA',
 'FG%',
 '3P',
 '3PA',
 '3P%',
 'FT',
 'FTA',
 'FT%',
 'ORB',
 'DRB',
 'TRB',
 'AST',
 'STL',
 'BLK',
 'TOV',
 'PF',
 'PTS',
 'GmSc',
 '+/-'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following to remove the 4th column from the dataframe `df` :

```py
df = df.drop(df.columns[4], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest hack you can do is this:

```
new_cols = df.columns.tolist()
new_cols[4] = 'col4'
new_cols[6] = 'col6'
df.columns = new_cols
```

This will replace the column values as per your requirement.